# How to implement SQL ORDER BY like funtionality in python?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of objects like this

```
time_slots = ['<TimeSlot: capacity: 1, number: 5>',
 '<TimeSlot: Room: capacity: 3, number: 2>',
 '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 1>',
 '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 6>',
 '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 1>',
 '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 3>']
```

I want to sort the above object on the basis of number and capacity.

Basically, I want to implement this-

```
ORDER BY number, capacity;
```

I can access the properties of every object by using something like-

```
time_slots[i].number
```

I have to implement this logic in python. Can someone please help me with this?

Edit: This is a simplified version of the actual problem. Please see the actual problem
[stackoverflow.com/q/75664227/20443528](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75664227/20443528)

Comment: Might be easier to throw it in a data frame and let that handle your sorting for you. Do you want to implement it at a class level ?

Comment: @Umar.H I want to implement a normal python program.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a method to the `sorted` function to specify the attributes to sort by returned in a tuple. Something like this should work:

```
sorted(time_slots, key=lambda x: (x.number, x.capacity))
```

Comment: After seeing your solution I have been forced to give a clearer problem. Earlier I gave a simplified version of the problem for easier understanding

Comment: At this stage it is really a competely different question. Rather than have people try to update their answers - you would be better to revert your edit, accept/close the 'simple' question and post a completely new question for new answers.

Comment: I did what you said. Here is the link to the actual problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/75664227/20443528

Comment: Great - you should also close this question - either by accepting an answer or just closing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `quotes` to make it a valid python:

```
l=['<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 1>', '<TimeSlot: Room: capacity: 3, number: 2>', '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 6>','<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 1>', '<TimeSlot: capacity: 1, number: 5>', '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 3>']

sorted(l,key=lambda x:x.split('capacity')[1][2])

#
['<TimeSlot: capacity: 1, number: 5>',
 '<TimeSlot: Room: capacity: 3, number: 2>',
 '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 1>',
 '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 6>',
 '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 1>',
 '<TimeSlot: capacity: 4, number: 3>']
```

`Explanation`:

We are splitting by `'capacity'` keyword, there will be `2` elements in the list formed after split. Then you have to index them to get the numeric value from it.

Comment: This is a simplified version of the actual problem. Please see the actual problem stackoverflow.com/q/75664227/20443528