# How to implement SQL ORDER BY like functionality if the first parameter is a function call in python?

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I have a list of objects like this

```
time_slots = [
<TimeSlot: number: 1, capacity: 4, advance: 10, from: 02:00:00, till: 08:00:00>,
<TimeSlot: number: 2, capacity: 3, advance: 17, from: 01:00:00, till: 04:00:00>,
<TimeSlot: number: 3, capacity: 3, advance: 17, from: 01:00:00, till: 04:00:00>,
<TimeSlot: number: 4, capacity: 1, advance: 17, from: 03:00:00, till: 08:00:00>,
<TimeSlot: number: 5, capacity: 4, advance: 17, from: 02:00:00, till: 07:00:00>,
<TimeSlot: number: 6, capacity: 3, advance: 17, from: 02:00:00, till: 09:00:00>,
<TimeSlot: number: 7, capacity: 2, advance: 17, from: 03:00:00, till: 08:00:00>
]
```

I want to sort the above object on the basis of duration (till - from) and capacity.

Basically, I want to implement this-

```
ORDER BY duration(till - from), capacity;
```

I can access the properties of every object by using something like-

```
time_slots[i].number
```

I sorted the list by duration like this-

```
from datetime import date, datetime

def bubbleSort(time_slots):
    swapped = False
    # Looping from size of array from last index[-1] to index [0]
    for n in range(len(time_slots)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(n):
            if (datetime.combine(date.today(), time_slots[i].available_till) - datetime.combine(date.today(), time_slots[i].available_from)) > (datetime.combine(date.today(), time_slots[i + 1].available_till) - datetime.combine(date.today(), time_slots[i + 1].available_from)):
                swapped = True
                # swapping data if the element is less than next element in the array
                time_slots[i], time_slots[i + 1] = time_slots[i + 1], time_slots[i]       
        if not swapped:
            # exiting the function if we didn't make a single swap
            # meaning that the array is already sorted.
            return

bubbleSort(time_slots)
```

I do not know how to do the second part and make a list which implements `ORDER BY bubbleSort(time_slots), capacity;` logic.

I have to implement this logic in python. Can someone please help me with this?

Side note: This problem is actually the real problem. The earlier problem I gave was a simplified one and those answers which I received will not work.

Comment: And why do you implement bubble sort instead of using Python's sorting functionality?

Comment: @KellyBundy Have you even read the question? If you can do it using Python's sorting functionality then please show me. Also now I have made it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I want to implement this-
>
> `ORDER BY duration(till - from), capacity;`

Sure; [`sorted()` and `list.sort()` both support a `key=` function argument](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions), and tuples are naturally sorted like you want, so have the function return a 2-tuple á la

```
time_slots.sort(key=lambda slot: (slot.till - slot.from, capacity))
```

and voilà - `time_slots` is now sorted primarly by length of slot, secondarily by capacity.

Comment: This can't be what they have trouble with, as they were already [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75663769/12671057) all of that except the subtraction, so that's gotta be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following be suitable?

Get the duration as a float and sort by duration then capacity?

```
from datetime import datetime
# calculate duration as number of hours (as a float)
def duration(dict):
    duration_time = datetime.strptime(dict["till"], '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(dict["from"], '%H:%M:%S')
    return duration_time.total_seconds() / 3600
# Sort by duration then by capacity
sorted(time_slots, key=lambda d: (duration(d), d['capacity']))
```

Assuming you cast the objects in the list to dicts.